# Не срабатывает jQuery

Tags: jquery, скрипт, javascript, веб-программирование

Не работает скрипт, а точнее jquery, вроде все как надо, не пойму. Загружаю с локального сервера. Простейший скрипт. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто может.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
        <title>Мото</title>
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript/"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

$(document).ready(function() {

   alert('text');

});
```

Comment: @Сергей Сидоренко, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Сергей Сидоренко, эти три строчки кода - это единственное, что в файле script.js? пути указаны верно? Есть ли какие-нибудь правила mod_rewrite и есть ли ошибки в консоли?

Comment: В каком каталоге находиться сам файл с указанным кодом? на случай, если, например, в папке "htmlCodePages" а не в верхнем уровне с папкой js - тогда нужно подняться на каталог выше, добавив в начале ../

Answer (score 1):

Явно проблема из-за пути к файлам скриптов. Если прописываете относительный путь к файлу, то следует добавлять точку и слеш в начале.

```
<script src="./js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript/"></script>
<script src="./js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

То же самое касается и подключения стилей css.

Comment: ну вообще нет, если в начале пути не стоит `/` то путь считается относительно файла, точка не нужна